# Store bought Mayonnaise is too vinegary?

Tags: mayonnaise

I haven't made mayonnaise myself but the one Ive liked while eating out, is the one that tasted like a 'smooth creamy salt-sugary eggy' paste. However I happened to buy a bottle of imported mayonnaise, and it had a very sharp vinegary kick to it, which I am kind of allergic to. How can I remove that 'vinegarnishness' from my store bought mayonnaise.

EDIT: The ingredient list: Water, vegetable oil (soyabean and/or canola),distilled vinegar, modified food starch, egg yolk, sugar, contains less than 2% of salt, spices(black pepper, mustard flour),potassium sorbate as preservative, phosphoric acid, xanthan gum, lactic acid, lemon juice concentrate, artificial flavour, beta carotene.

Comment: Have you tried making homemade mayonnaise?

Comment: What country are you in? And since you said "imported", what country did the mayonnaise come from? And certainly I would look for mayo in a jar, not a squeeze bottle. Without getting into brands, you might add more details about the mayo in question.

Comment: @user3169 Am I allowed to discuss specific brands? I'm in India, and the mayonnaise was from USA.

Comment: Yes, brands are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. I hate vinegar too, and can assure you, there is no way to remove the taste. If dilution works for you, do it, it doesn't matter what you use. If you really can't stand the taste, dilution won't matter, then you have to throw out the bottle.

"It doesn't matter what you use" means that there is no specific thing to mix in which will be better at "removing" the vinegar smell than some other thing. This is because you are not removing or changing anything about the smell, you are simply diluting - if you mix 50/50 with the filler, the mixture will only smell of vinegar half as strong. Which filler you use matters very much for the overall taste impression, it can happen that you dislike the new combination much more than you dislike pure vinegar. We can't tell you which combinations will make it better for you and which worse, it is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: What _have_ you tried though? It would seem that there should be quite effective ways to modify the “vinegarishness” of something like mayonaise – like, obviously, raising the pH. (I can't imagine this to actually improve the taste, but then, _I_ greatly like vinegar, so...)

Comment: I tried adding honey and it became worse.

Comment: @leftaroundabout changing the pH only changes the perception of sourness. The vinegar aroma remains.

Comment: @user2277550 OK, there is no guarantee that you personally will like a new combination of tastes better than you liked it uncombined. "It doesn't matter what you use" meant that no thing will be more or less efficient in removing the vinegary smell than another one. If you happen to dislike the "honey + vinegar" combination more than you dislike pure vinegar (which is not something we can predict) then the overall effect will be worse for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your ingredients list, I think the eggs are too far down. When I check the mayo I have (US):

Soybean oil
Water
Whole eggs and egg yolks
vinegar
salt
sugar

Of course you can't tell the actual quantities, but vinegar is lower on the list.  Also water.
I would check the ingredient lists of various brands you can find (should be online). A thick mayo that you would scoop with a spoon (as opposed to a squeeze bottle) should indicate more egg content.